# Django Nested model or serializers

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm new in Django and I have a simple use case to parse a nested json file. My json file doesn't include key name and my data type is like this:

<car_factory>:<car_details>

current models:

```
class CarFactory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)    

class CarModel(models.Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    name = models.ForeignKey(CarFactory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And here is my input json file.

```
             {
                "BMW":[
                {
                  "model":"3",
                  "price":"500"
                },
                {
                  "model":"5",
                  "price":"600"
                }
              ],
                "TOYOTA":[
                {
                  "model":"X",
                  "price":"300"
                },
                {
                  "model":"H",
                  "price":"400"
                },
                {
                  "model":"S",
                  "price":"500"
                }
              ]
             }
```

Current serializers

```
class CarModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model: str = serializers.CharField()
    price: int = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
       model = CarModel
       fields = ("model", "price")


class CarCompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    models = CarModelSerializer(many=True)
    name = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = CarCompany
        fields = ("name", "models")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        car_company = CarCompany.objects.create(name=validated_data.get("name"))
        for model in vaidated_data.get("models"):
              car_company.models_set.create(**model)
        return {"name": car_company.name}
   
   def to_representation(self, instance):
       """Override the representation of the data"""
       data = super().to_representation(instance)
       return { data.get("name"): data.get("models")}

# in views

  ...
  def post(self, request):
      for (key, value) in request.data.items():
          serializer = serializers.CarCompanySerializer(name=key, models=value)
          serializer.is_valid(raise_expection=True)
          serializer.save()

      return Response(....)
```

Comment: Let me try to understand the question. You are required to add those details provided in the input json to your db?

Comment: Yes @VJMagar , correct.

Comment: ok, and those are supposed to the car company names with the models and their prices n the input. Just wanted to know if you have serializers for these

Comment: Exactly. And this is the exact format of json file I provided here. I just don't know how  to create the relation in serializers

Answer (score 3):

You can approach this problem by overriding the serializers of the CarCompany Serializer.

```
# assumption you already have car company serializer and car model serializers

# serializers
class CarModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model: str = serializers.CharField()
    price: int = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
       model = CarModel
       fields = ("model", "price")


class CarCompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    models = CarModelSerializer(many=True)
    name = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = CarCompany
        fields = ("name", "models")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        car_company = CarCompany.objects.create(name=validated_data.get("name"))
        for model in vaidated_data.get("models"):
              car_company.models_set.create(**model)
        return {"name": car_company.name}
   
   def to_representation(self, instance):
       """Override the representation of the data"""
       data = super().to_representation(instance)
       return { data.get("name"): data.get("models")}

# in views

  ...
  def post(self, request):
      for (key, value) in request.data.items():
          serializer = serializers.CarCompanySerializer(name=key, models=value)
          serializer.is_valid(raise_expection=True)
          serializer.save()

      return Response(....)


  ...
```

Comment: Thank you VJ. your code is creating slightly different output than my case:
My structure is like this <car_factory>: <model and price>

{
    "name": "",
    "models": []
}

instead of 

{
    "BMW": [
       "model" : "open",
       "price" : 36000
   ]
}

Comment: I think you can achieve this by updating the 'to_representation' of the CarCompanySerializer. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: from name = models.CharField() I get the following error. 
AttributeError: 'ListSerializer' object has no attribute 'CharField'

Comment: Hi sorry for the typo. I have updated the code. It should have been name = serializers.CharField() not models.CharField()