# How to change a queryset in Django?

Tags: python, django, serialization

I try to change output of **Django** serializer.

Class-based view has function **get_projects** that returns queryset of **Contract** instances.

```
projects = Project.objects.all()
contracts = Contract.objects.filter(project__in=projects)
```

Relationship of **Contract** and **Project** is one-to-many:

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
```

Now I have such **MySerializer**:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    project_guid = serializers.UUIDField(source='guid')
    project_name = serializers.CharField(source='name')
    contract_guid = serializers.UUIDField(source='guid')
    contract_number = serializers.CharField(source='number')
```

**MySerializer's** response is:

```
[
  {
    "projectGuid": "project_guid_1",
    "projectName": "project_name_1",
    "contractGuid": "contract_guid_1",
    "contractNumber": "contract_number_1"
  },
  {
    "projectGuid": "project_guid_1",
    "projectName": "project_name_1",
    "contractGuid": "contract_guid_2",
    "contractNumber": "contract_number_2"
  },
  {
    "projectGuid": "project_guid_2",
    "projectName": "project_name_2",
    "contractGuid": "contract_guid_4",
    "contractNumber": "contract_number_4"
  },
  {
    "projectGuid": "project_guid_2",
    "projectName": "project_name_2",
    "contractGuid": "contract_guid_5",
    "contractNumber": "contract_number_5"
  },
]
```

I would like to change serializer output - to group contracts for exact projects like this:

```
[
 {
  "project_guid": "project_guid_1",
  "project_name": "project_name_1",
  "contracts": [
    {
      "contract_guid": "contract_guid_1",
      "contract_number": "contract_number_1",
    },
    {
      "contract_guid": "contract_guid_2",
      "contract_number": "contract_number_2",
    },
    ....
  ]
 },
 {
  "project_guid": "project_guid_2",
  "project_name": "project_name_2",
  "contracts": [
    {
      "contract_guid": "contract_guid_4",
      "contract_number": "contract_number_4",
    },
    {
      "contract_guid": "contract_guid_5",
      "contract_number": "contract_number_5",
    },
    ....
  ]
 },
]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You should first create `ContractSerializer` and use it serializer inside `ProjectSerializer` contracts field `contracts = ContractSerializer(blabla...`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Nested model or serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66184629/django-nested-model-or-serializers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the queryset.
I refactored **qs** in **get_projects**:

```
projects = Project.objects.filter(active=True).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('contract_set', queryset=Contract.objects.filter(**filters), to_attr='contracts')
    )
```

And refactored **MySerializer** like this:

```
class ContractSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    contract_guid = serializers.UUIDField(source='guid')
    contract_number = serializers.CharField(source='number')

class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    project_guid = serializers.UUIDField(source='guid')
    project_name = serializers.CharField(source='name')
    contracts = ContractSerializer(many=True)
```

Thanks to `SerhiiL` for hint with **prefetch_related**.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can try this

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Contract
       fields = ["contract_guid", "contract_number"]

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contracts = ContactSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Project 
        fields = ["project_guid", "project_name", "contracts"]
```

And don't forget use **prefetch related** for optimization your query.